# Decommissioning PKI - How do I set a CRL Next update to null?

Tags: windows, encryption, certificate-authority, ad-certificate-services, pki

I am planning on deploying two Windows 2008R2 PKIs: One for legacy devices that don't support SHA-2 / ECP and another one that does support it.

When the time comes to decommission the SHA1 environment I want to have the CRL `next update` be the last one ever published.

How do I configure this correctly in a Windows based CA?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft PKI blog has an extensive set of instructions for decommissioning a PKI tree, more is involved than just setting next update to null

http://blogs.technet.com/b/pki/archive/2012/01/27/steps-needed-to-decommission-an-old-certification-authority-without-affecting-previously-issued-certificates-and-then-switching-all-operations-to-a-new-certification-authority.aspx